# Python PyOt5 OpenGL Indexbuffer syntax

Tags: python-3.x, opengl, pyqt5

I seem to have trouble figuring out how to properly use the index buffer in conjunction with glDrawElements. Software basis is:

- Python 3.5.2
- OpenGL 4.5 (version functions 4.1 core loaded)
- Qt 5.7.1

When I create and use the buffer like this:

```
ibo = QOpenGLBuffer(QOpenGLBuffer.IndexBuffer)
ibo.create()
.... //do some stuff like filling with data here
glDrawElements(GL_POINTS, 1, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, ibo)
```

I get an error saying:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ogltest.py", line 134, in paintGL
    glDrawElements(GL_POINTS, 1, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, ibo)
TypeError: QOpenGLFunctions_4_1_Core.glDrawElements(): array must be a sequence or a buffer
```

I believe it is referring to the last argument.
According to the docs (http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qopenglbuffer.html) an instance of this object (QOpenGLBuffer with the type set to IndexBuffer) is supposed to be used in a glDrawElements() call. Seemingly it does not.

A built-in array type, contrary to the documentation, works great:

```
ia = array.array('I')
.... //do the same stuff
glDrawElements(GL_POINTS, 1, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, ia)
```

, however I suspect that the glDrawElements() wrapper does the uploading to GPU each time. If this is supposed to be the correct way to use the draw call, then I would like to know the usage scenario for a QOpenGLBuffer of IndexBuffer type.

Any pointers are much appreciated!

-Tasche

Comment: Seems like I did not find this post, but the above link is exactly this problem. I did find a bit different solution, but the one posted in the other question is more general and comprehensive.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured it out.
Unfortunately, this is not documented anywhere (neither at Khronos' OpenGL docs nor on any Qt documentation, or at least I did not find it):

When you intend to use an index buffer residing on the GPU, you pass the Null pointer to the draw call (C++). In Python, this translates to passing "None":

```
glDrawElements(GL_POINTS, 1, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, None)
```

Don't forget to bind the correct IBO.

Comment: I assume you properly read the [OpenGL specification](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/glspec45.core.pdf) to be able to come with the assessment that it isn't documented. I would say that is also [perfectly described here as well](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glDrawElements.xhtml).

Comment: @Vallentin I read that Khronos page several times now. Maybe my english is not good enough, but I what i infer from that documentation, is that the call is "starting at indices to" do stuff. The answer I posted passes "None", and the call certainly is not starting at "None". In the param desc is also says "Specifies a pointer to the location where the indices are stored.". I specify the indices in an "IndexBuffer", not in "None". I guess that documentation was not perfectly enough for me.

Comment: the key points are: 1. use type 'I' array.array, 2: gl.glDrawElements(gl.GL_TRIANGLES, self.n_index, gl.GL_UNSIGNED_INT, self.index_array)